# How to insert random, continuous gaps of specific length and number into vector?

Tags: r, vector, random, na

I need to create several datasets with different, random number and length of continuous gaps. I thought of creating a vector with NA for multiplying with the original dataset. Here's the code I got so far for one dataset (the whole simulation will take place with MonteCarlo):

```
    For gap definition:

    size1 <- sample(1:40, size=1)
    length <- sample(1:480, size=size1)

    Expressing as different vectors with NA:      

    vec <- list()

    for (i in 1:length(length)){
    vec[[i]] <- seq(1:length[i])
    vec[[i]] <- replace(c(vec[[i]]), values=NA)
    }
```

I further need to insert these vectors randomly, but coherently and not adjacent (with a space of at least one) into the vector of a specific length (e.g. 37000).

```
   x <- numeric(37000)
   x <- replace(x, 1)
```

Does anyone know a good way to do this? 
Cheers a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best way to do it,
but it's an option:

```
vector_length <- 37000L
num_gaps <- sample(40L, 1L) # 40 is the max amount of gaps
gap_lengths <- sample(480L, num_gaps) # 480 is the max length of a gap

# initialize
overlaps <- TRUE
gap_ends <- Inf
while (any(overlaps) || any(gap_ends > vector_length)) {
  gap_starts <- sort(sample(vector_length, num_gaps))
  gap_ends <- gap_starts + gap_lengths - 1L
  # make sure the distance between each gap is at least 1
  overlaps <- gap_starts[-1L] - gap_ends[-num_gaps] <= 1L
}

x <- numeric(vector_length)
for (i in seq_along(gap_starts)) {
  x[gap_starts[i]:gap_ends[i]] <- NA_real_
}
```